# Flashing From Source Control Icon

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-commit

Visual Studio Code's `Source Control` icon is flashing every 3 seconds. The below GIF has been sped up ...

[image]

When I look at the outputs after running the command `Git: Show Git Output` it seems to do more than just get a status, and the second command actually fails.

```
git status -z -uall
git config --get commit.template 
git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track)%00%(upstream:remotename)%00%(upstream:remoteref) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
```

The `git config ...` is failing after running it on the command line:

[image]

How can this be resolved?

---

- VS Code Version: 1.77.1
- Git Version:     2.33.1.windows.1

*Both of those are the latest version as of this post*

- Disabling all extensions and looking in the source control section shows this:

[image]

Comment: "_When I look at the outputs after running the command Git: Show Git Output it seems to do more than just get a status, and the second command actually fails._" show **actual error messages** from running git commands and not just a broken shell prompt please.

Comment: I've updated the screenshot. For an error is not showing up past the broken shell prompt `Error`. I do not AFAIK have any templates in git.

Answer (score 1):

The reason in my case was a file in the worktree being appended (a logfile). 3 seconds seems to be the interval at which the `git` plugin is getting file change notifications. Although the entire directory was in `.gitignore`, the plugin does not take that into account ([here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/458191928c5d7b7578512dd8164d646f7dd6a728/extensions/git/src/repository.ts#L866-L890) you can see only the changes under `.git` are filtered).

To find what file is triggering the refreshes, in vscode set `Developer: Set Log Level...` -> `Git` -> `Debug`, then check `Git` output.